# Makefile does not find functions in c

Tags: c, makefile

I wrote the following makefile:

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = Car.o Guide.o GuideSystem.o
DEBUG_OBJS = Car_debug.o Guide_debug.o GuideSystem_debug.o
SOURCE = Car.c Guide.c GuideSystem.c
HEADER = Car.h Guide.h GuideSystem.h list.h set.h
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror
LIBM = -L. -lib
EXEC = test.exe test1.exe test2.exe test2_debug.exe
TEST_O = test1.o test2.o test2_debug.o test.o

#make test1.exe
test1.exe : $(OBJS) test1.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DNDEBUG $(OBJS) test1.o $(LIBM) -o $@

#make test2.exe
test2.exe : $(OBJS) test2.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DNDEBUG $(OBJS) test2.o $(LIBM) -o $@

#make test2_debug.exe
test2_debug.exe : $(OBJS) test2_debug.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g $(OBJS) test2_debug.o $(LIBM) -o $@

#make test.exe
test.exe : $(OBJS) test.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DNDEBUG $(OBJS) test.o $(LIBM) -o $@

#Testing (no asserts)
test.o : test.c Guide.h GuideSystem.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $*.c $(CFLAGS)
test1.o : test1.c Guide.h GuideSystem.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $*.c $(CFLAGS)
test2.o : test2.c Guide.h GuideSystem.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $*.c $(CFLAGS)
Guide.o : Guide.c Guide.h list.h Car.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $*.c $(CFLAGS)
GuideSystem.o : GuideSystem.c GuideSystem.h set.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $*.c $(CFLAGS)
Car.o : Car.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $*.c $(CFLAGS)

#Debug testing
test2_debug.o : test2.c Guide.h GuideSystem.h
    $(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) test2.c -o $@
Guide_debug.o : Guide.c Guide.h list.h Car.h
    $(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) Guide.c -o $@
GuideSystem_debug.o : GuideSystem.c GuideSystem.h set.h
    $(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) GuideSystem.c -o $@
Car_debug.o : Car.h
    $(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) Car.c -o $@

#Clean builds
clean :
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEBUG_OBJS) $(EXEC) $(TEST_O)
```

When I run `make test` I get:

```
gcc   test.o   -o test
test.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `createGuide'
... more undefined functions
```

I have some problem with the makefile but I can't seem to find the problem. All of the other `make` options work properly, only `make test` fails.

As I understand it should run:

```
gcc -c -DNDEBUG -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors test.c
gcc -o test.exe -DNDEBUG Guide.o GuideSystem.o Car.o test.o -L. -lib
```

What could be the problem? How can I solve it? Do I have a problem with my makefile?

Comment: Where is the `test` target? I think you're running into an implicit rule here, where `make` is assuming you want to make a binary named `test` from `test.o`.

Comment: You should run `make test.exe` if you want to build the `test.exe` target you've defined in your makefile.  You can't run `make test` because (as hmm says) you didn't define a target named `test`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define any `test` target, so `make` guessed wrongly that you wanted to make a program named `test` just from `test.o` (implicit rule).

What you should probably insert in `Makefile` is:

```
test: test.exe test2.exe
    ./test.exe
    ./test2.exe
.PHONY: test
```